# Can I tell which software generated a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Given a PDF file. Can I find out which software/libraries (e.g. PDFBox, Adobe Acrobat, iText...)  where used to created/edit it?

Comment: how about this ?" http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/extract-info-about-pdf-file

Comment: If I understood you answers correctly, the only way to do so is to check the meta data? That is, no extra information can be embedded in the actual file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try opening the file in Adobe Acrobat Reader and look at the properties.

You can find this in: File -> Properties in Adobe Acrobat Reader after you open the pdf file.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The Adobe specification defines the Producer field (see 'Mac OS X 10.5.6 Quartz PDFContext' in screenshot nimeshjm's answer) as the name of the application that "converted from another format to PDF". In case of generating a PDF programmatically, the PDF isn't really converted so you will normally find the name of the generating SDK here.

The Creator field is related and is defined as the name of the application that created the document from which the PDF was converted. This is typically MS Word or so.

Note that this is all by convention. In practice, you cannot really rely on this and you may encounter for example empty Producer fields.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably get away without any PDF libraries for this type of operation. It won't be 100% reliable but I think you can probably assume 99% reliability.

So... write some code to open your PDF as a text stream and seaarch down for /Producer. You will find something like this:

```
69 0 obj
<< 
/Creator (PDF+Forms 2.0)
/CreationDate (D:20010627111809)
/Title (Demo)
/Producer (Cardiff Software - TELEform 7.0)
/ModDate (D:20010627111810-05'00')
>>
```

Grab the bits between the parentheses and Bob's your uncle. Technically the text can be stored in other formats to but I think those will be pretty uncommon for this particular type of entry.

If you can't find anything here then look for the XMP data which is always guaranteed to be in clear text. It will look something like this,

```
39 0 obj
<</Subtype/XML/Length 15172/Type/Metadata>>stream
<?xpacket begin='ï»¿' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.0-c320 44.293068, Sun Jul 08 2007 18:10:11">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:xap="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
    xmlns:xapGImg="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/g/img/"
    xmlns:xapMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
    xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
   dc:format="application/pdf"
   xap:CreatorTool="Adobe Illustrator CS2"
   xap:CreateDate="2006-05-04T15:53:27-07:00"
   xap:ModifyDate="2006-05-04T15:53:27-07:00"
   xap:MetadataDate="2006-05-04T15:53:27-07:00"
   xapMM:DocumentID="uuid:61AC83CBC0DBDA11A32BC847EF128E34"
   xapMM:InstanceID="uuid:cba15bf3-d7da-4a4e-a563-fc20d13e258a"
   pdf:Producer="Adobe PDF library 7.77">
   <dc:title>
    <rdf:Alt>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">3.01 PDF components</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Alt>
   </dc:title>
...
```

The combination of these two is going to be practically always right. If you want 100% reliablity then by all means use a PDF library but for many purposes this should be sufficient.

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's what I work on. It's what I know. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is usually difficult to determine which software actually designed a PDF because most of Microsoft Office product can convert an edited file to PDF. By this I mean, opening a regular typed document, you have the option to save it as PDF. If you are familiar with Powerpoint slides, it can be easy to tell based on the design once the file is in PDF.

Where as on the other hand, Adobe Acrobat has the ability to create the file like those application forms we often download (from an embassy site, immigration site, etc).

Other software such as Adobe Photoshop, Illustrator, etc... can save files as PDF. Hope this help.